# Bash script to open multiple terminal tabs and run some scripts

Tags: bash, ubuntu, terminal

Since, my product follow a micro-service architecture, I want to run multiple apps same time.
I want to open new terminal tabs and run some commands in that. Can you help me to write a bash script to perform these action. Its a repeated task I need to do daily/restart my system. I would like get it automated.

eg:

```
Tab1: 'cd Documents/my_app1; rails s -p 4000'
Tab2: 'cd Documents/my_app2; rails s -p 5000'
Tab3: 'cd Desktop/angular_app; yarn start --port 3000'
```

etc..

So, I need a script to run this with one command.

Comment: Well, not without knowing what desktop and what tabbed console application you are using? For instance in KDE3 a simple bash script calling DCOP on konsole can setup as many tabs as you like and run a different command within each at startup -- but I seriously doubt you are using KDE3... (I am)

Comment: I dont have much idea regarding these things. I just use pre installed terminal in Ubuntu. Im new to this.

Comment: Manipulating a GUI terminal may be not quite convenient or portable. You can use tools like [tag:expect] (which uses [tag:tcl]). If you are more comfortable with shell scripts then take a look at my [sexpect (Expect for Shells)](https://github.com/clarkwang/sexpect).

Comment: By the way, it's not very clear why you need to run the commands in GUI terminal Tabs. Can you just put the command running in background (like `sleep 10 &`) as shell's jobs?

Answer (score 1):

What's with the tabs?

```
gnome-terminal -- /bin/bash -c 'cd Documents/my_app1; rails s -p 4000'
gnome-terminal -- /bin/bash -c 'cd Documents/my_app2; rails s -p 5000'
gnome-terminal -- /bin/bash -c 'cd Desktop/angular_app; yarn start --port 3000'
```

Comment: Much easier than DCOP. I haven't used gnome since Gnome 2, but I did like gnome-terminal....

Comment: It popup a new window and closes sooner automatically :(

Comment: @DavidC.Rankin can you tell what is DCOP and how can I proceed ?

Comment: Oh, I'm sorry. DCOP was a predecessor to DBUS for inter-process communication for KDE providing superior message length compared to IPC. It has long since been replaced, except for those running KDE3.  gnome-terminal should be scriptable from within gnome-shell. I haven't used gnome in a decade, so I cannot give you further details on it. There is an older question on [Some fast way to save and restore tabs of Terminal?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/310705/some-fast-way-to-save-and-restore-tabs-of-terminal) here.